# WPF ListView Multi-Select MVVM w/ minimal code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to implement in WPF a way for the user to select multiple items in one box and via button click add those selected items to the other box.

I am trying to adhere to MVVM w/ minimal code behind.  The solutions I find show the DataContext being manipulated via the View code behind which I am trying to avoid.

I think my issue is I do not know how to toggle the IsSelected from xaml, but not sure.

[image]

XAML

```
<ListView
                            ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionMode="Multiple"

                            DisplayMemberPath="state"
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Margin="5"
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            Height="125"
                            Name="lvAvailableStates"
                            Grid.RowSpan="6" 
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>

<Button
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="10"
                            Command="{Binding AddSelectedStatesCommand}"
                        Content=">>" />
```

ViewModel

```
 private ObservableCollection<SelectableItemWrapper<states_approved>> _selectedStates;
    public ObservableCollection<SelectableItemWrapper<states_approved>> SelectedStates
    {
        get { return _selectedStates; }
        set
        {

            _selectedStates = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void AddSelectedStates(object obj)
    {
        var selected = SelectedStates.Where(s => s.IsSelected)
            .Select(s => s.Item)
            .ToList();

        StatesApproved = selected;
    }

public CustomCommand AddSelectedStatesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new CustomCommand(AddSelectedStates, CanExecute);
        }
    }
```

Selected Item Wrapper

```
public class SelectableItemWrapper<T>
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is your actual issue? There is only ListView in the sample markup you have posted. How is the AddSelectedStates method supposed to be called?

Comment: By clicking the button with >> in it.  ie, user selects 3 states in left listview, clicks the >> button, and it populates the right list view.  I will add the button code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView` has internal property to determine which item is selected and it also has `SelectedItems` to determine multiple selected items. However, this plural `SelectedItems` of `ListView` is not bindable. So, the solution is to pass them as a `CommandParameter`.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvAvailableStates"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStates, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStates, Mode=TwoWay}" => remove this!
          ...

<Button Command="{Binding AddSelectedStatesCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=lvAvailableStates}" => add this!
        ...
```

In the VM

```
private void AddSelectedStates(IEnumerable<SelectableItemWrapper<states_approved>> selectedItems)
{
    StatesApproved = selectedItems
        .Select(s => s.Item) // only retrieve the Item
        .ToList();
}
```

As you can see at this point, you don't even really need the `SelectableItemWrapper` to set/unset the `IsSelected` property to begin with. You should just remove the wrapper and life will be easier.

Comment: Thank you good sir.  You solution worked and I only changed one thing which was I cast the obj to an ILIST and from there called Cast method and assigned it to StatesApproved.  Thank you so much for the help and I really wonder why SelectedItems is private to begin with.

Comment: [SelectedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) is not private. It is just readonly.